# enumerating permutations with exactly $k$ inversions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms

For a few days, I've been unsuccessfully trying to come up with an algorithm that enumerates the permutations of a set (of cardinality $= n$) with exactly $k$ inversions.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In $q-$ calculus (recall that $[n]_q=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$) there is the concept of $q-$factorial and is not hard to show that $$[n]_q!=[1]_1\cdots [n]_q=\sum _{i=0}^{\binom{n}{2}}A_{n,k}q^k,$$ where $A_{n,k}$ is the number of permutations of size $n$ with exactly $k$ inversions.
The proof of that is just by multiplying out and noticing that if you have a permutation of size $n-1$ with $\ell$ inversions, then you can create a permutation of $n$ by inserting $n$ in one of the available slots. Depending on where you put it, you will create a certain number of inversions. For example if $\pi = 21$ with $1$ inversion, I can place $3$ in these ways
$$\color{red}{3}21,2\color{red}{3}1,21\color{red}{3}.$$ Creating $1+\color{red}{2},1+\color{red}{1},1+\color{red}{0}$ inversions. Use this recursion to enumerate them.
**Edit:**
Here you have what I meant in Python/Sage

```
def tal(n,k):
    if n==1:
        if k==0:
            return [[1]]
        return []
    s = []
    for j in range(0,n):
        if k-j<0:
            break
        t = tal(n-1,k-j)
        for x in t:
            y = x[:len(x)-j]
            y.append(n)
            y.extend(x[len(x)-j:])
            s.append(y) 
    return s
tal(5,3)
```

Comment: ok thank you ! I should have explained in more details my question : apart from these mathematical properties, is there a way to *enumerate* these specific permutations? An algorithm that does the work?

Comment: @KeryannMassin That is the algorithm. You send the recursion saving where you place each element. Should be recursive or also you can try to use a stack. Let me know if you see what I mean.

Comment: @KeryannMassin In other words, if you want the permutations of size $3$ with $2$ inversions. You place $3$ in the first spot and then you want the permutations with 0 inversions of size $2.$ etc..

Comment: @KeryannMassin I have added a code to make the case for why the recursion works. Let me know if this answers your question.